# Translator using a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, python-3.6

I'm trying to solve a problem that can be found in the Book *The Coder's Apprentice* by Pieter Spronck, in section 13.2.4. This is the code I wrote so far:

```
english_dutch = {"last":"laatst", "week":"week", "the":"de", "royal":"koninklijk",
    "festival":"feast", "hall":"hal", "saw":"zaag", "first":"eerst", "performance":"optreden",
    "of":"van", "a":"een", "new":"nieuw", "symphony":"symphonie", "by":"bij",
    "one":"een", "world":"wereld", "leading":"leidend", "modern":"modern",
    "composer":"componist", "composers:componisten" "two":"twee", "shed":"schuur", "sheds":"schuren"}

text = "Last week The Royal Festival Hall saw the first \
 performance of a new symphony by one of the world's leading \
 modern composers, Arthur 'Two-Sheds' Jackson."


def clean(t):
    t = t.lower()
    t = t.split()
    new_t = ""
    for word in t:
        new_word = ""
        for letter in word:
            if "a" <= letter <= "z":
                new_word += letter
            if letter == "-":
                new_word += " "
            else:
                continue
        new_t += new_word + " "
    return new_t


def translate(t):
    translation = ""
    for word in t.split():
        if english_dutch.get(word):
            translation += english_dutch[word] + " "
        else:
            translation += word + " "
    return translation


def auto_correct():
    news = ""
    a = translate(clean(text)).split()
    for word in a:
        if len(word) > 1:
            news += word + " "
    print(news)

auto_correct()
```

It seems to work OK, but when I run it, the words "composers" and "two" are not translated.

Comment: Search for a typo in your code.

Comment: or split using regexes.

Comment: Though .split() is easy, it is not effective for data where you have punctuation. You should try and implement Jean's answer below, it will be better for most situations, but only if you are allowed import modules such as Regex. Note - Regex can be used with other programming languages.

Comment: @Poppinyoshi thanks but my answer doesn't really answer the question. So I removed it. I suggested using regexes to split so you don't have to use `cleanup`: `for word in (x for x in re.split("\W+",text) if x):`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I'm aware. Of course Regex will be a more complete solution.

Answer (score 5):

You forgot a comma between the word `composers` and the word `two`. In addiotion you wrote `"composers:componisten"` instead of `"composers":"componisten"`. Change your dictionary like so

```
 english_dutch = {"last":"laatst", "week":"week",
     "the":"de", "royal":"koninklijk",
     "festival":"feast", "hall":"hal",
     "saw":"zaag", "first":"eerst",
     "performance":"optreden",
     "of":"van", "a":"een",
     "new":"nieuw", "symphony":"symphonie",
     "by":"bij",
     "one":"een", "world":"wereld",
     "leading":"leidend", "modern":"modern",
     "composer":"componist",
     "composers":"componisten", "two":"twee",  # <- HERE
     "shed":"schuur", "sheds":"schuren"}
```

Why it passed undetected? Check this:

```
>>> {"composers:componisten" "two":"twee"}
{'composers:componistentwo': 'twee'}
```

Because the comma was missing and the colon was *within* the string, python concatenated the strings, creating a useless (but valid) key/value pair.

This behaviour is documented [here](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literal-concatenation)

> Multiple adjacent string literals (delimited by whitespace), possibly using different quoting conventions, are allowed, and their meaning is the same as their concatenation. Thus, "hello" 'world' is equivalent to "helloworld".

Comment: Ah, I noticed it! Such a stupid error... Many franks!

Comment: ok, there's a typo in the dictionary, but, but, it doesn't make sense. The problem is about `str.split` not doing the job. It won't work even after just fixing the dictionary

Comment: Besides the dict error, composers and Two aren't translated because string split yields `composers,` and `'Two-Sheds'`. Double error. Bad luck!

Comment: If you run the code you will see that they are being translated. As for your comment above, you are right, this answer is more fitted to the comment section as it is not imporving the code (as you did in your asnwer). I will remove this one.

Comment: don't remove it.  I didn't see the "clean" stuff. But your answer would be better if it explained _why_ the typo doesn't trigger an error.

Comment: Oh well, have not noticed it either :).

Comment: I have edited to add why no error appears. Rare case where typo questions are worth answering.